# Unit test - What double (actor) are entities (model classes)?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

Conceptual question here about entities in unit tests. Trying to fully understand the concepts.

How should I name my entities in my unit tests?... I mean, I usually create a class like PersonMock that has different methods like "newPerson1()", "newPerson2()" and so on, each method returning an instance with different state for testing different scenarios.

But it looks like this is not the pure concept of "mock" (currently reading a unit testing book). For what I understand, entities (and entity buiders) are not mocks (and not stubs, fakes, dummies, etc)... what are they in unit testing? Just model builders?

How do you guys manage and name these objects responsible for creating entities that will be used in the tests? (Like PersonMock above.)

And any other further best practice tips are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called fixtures. Mocks can be a subset. So in your case, I would have a `PersonFixture` that provides useful flavours of `Person` to use when testing.

Here are the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture) and [JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-fixtures) definitions of a fixture.

Comment: Thanks Henri. That's what I was looking for.